# Xmx128M -Xms16M BinaryCalculator error in java

Tags: java

I have the following script:

```
public class BinaryCalculator{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String  errorFormat = "Format error: java BinaryConversion <int>"; 
        String  messageFirstPart = "Binary representation of "; 
        String  messageSecondPart = " is ";

        int binary[] = new int[40];
        int num=0;
        int index = 0;

        if(args.length==0){
            System.out.println(errorFormat);
        }else{  
            try {
                num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);            

                System.out.print(messageFirstPart+num+messageSecondPart);               

                while(num < 0){
                    binary[index++] = num%2;
                    num = num/2;
                }

                for(int i = index-1;i >= 0;i--){
                    System.out.print(binary[i]);
                }

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println(errorFormat);
                System.exit(1);
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

and when i try to execute it, suddenly appears the error:

```
$java -Xmx128M -Xms16M BinaryCalculator
Format error: java BinaryConversion <int>
```

I run by the following website: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php
Is there someone who knows it?

Thanks

Comment: Please write the command you use to execute the program.

Comment: How are you attempting to run the application?

Comment: I suggest not setting the heap size unless you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking for number of arguments but it seems you're not passing any arguments when you're running your code.

Try something like:

```
java BinaryCalculator 10
```

Comment: But where should i add this information? At the beginning of the script?

Comment: But i am using eclipse IDE and i don't know in which line i should add the information

Comment: the exercise says there are two semantic errors in this code. May you any idea which could be?